# server side pagination data tables

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, pagination

I want to implement server side pagination using data tables, I have may be  around 200 records,I understood how server side pagination works ,we send ajax requests  individually for each link ,Now   when we send parameters to server such as page number(draw) page start, if I want 10 records per page does it mean we should send 20 ajax requests  , for 200 records by incrementing the page number every time  and processing the data from server side and returning the json object every time?

This is how I implemented it  apart from syntaxt this is how I implemented it?

```
$('#tableEM').DataTable( {
     "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "sAjaxDataProp":"",
        "columns":[{"keyword":"keyword","updated_date":"updated_date","action":"delete"}],
        'paging': true,
        "ajax": {
             "url": "/rest/events/keywords/sereverPagination1",         
             type: "GET",
             data:{
                 "iDisplayStart":i,
                 "iDisplayLength":10,
                 "draw": draw,  
             },
             success: function (jsonEM)
             {
                   console.log(jsonEM)

                    for(var i=0; i<=jsonEM.length; i++){
                        console.log(jsonEM[i])

                        console.log(i)
                            $('#topicContainer').append('<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+jsonEM[i].keyword+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+jsonEM[i].updated_date+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+jsonEM[i].action+'</td>'+
                            '</tr>')
                    }
             }
        }
    } );
```

Is the implementation right? pls help .I am using spring  for back end

My implementation for the server side

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/events/keywords/sereverPagination1")
    public List<EventMonitor> getResults(@RequestParam(value="iDisplayStart",required=true)int iDisplayStart,@RequestParam(value="iDisplayLength",required=true)int iDisplayLength){

        ArrayList<EventMonitor> keywordList=(ArrayList<EventMonitor>) _eventMonitorDao.getTargetList(0);
    ArrayList<EventMonitor> sublist=    (ArrayList<EventMonitor>) keywordList.subList(iDisplayStart, iDisplayLength);
     return sublist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> do with php pass to mysql

and page like 2
it means $offset = page * perpage  = 40 -perpage = 20
`SELECT * FROM tbl
LIMIT $offset, $perpage`

Comment: Could you please expand it ,should I  send so  many requests? This is how I implemented it ..

Comment: yes as you saiid in question 20ajx request for 200 record your pagination url iike project.com/produncts?page=2&perpage=20  your php file do the other process

Comment: Please go through the  code I implemented is it correct?

Comment: yes you post require data but i make the server side for you!

Comment: I have updated with server side code pls    check and tell if it is right.

Comment: just post data that i recommand in answer with post or get and in backend get them do the following process in my answer